# How to correct this sql function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Create function GetDiffence (@difference float)
returns @Modify table
(Cod int, Pret float, Diferenta float)
as
begin
Insert @Modify
Select Cod, Pret, @difference-Pret as Diferenta
from PC_uri
order by Cod
Return
end

Select * from GetDiffence(350)
```

It's say that "create function must be the only statement in the batch sql". What is wrong here. I cant understand..... Its work fine but why i get this error,...

Comment: Place a `GO` on a separate line after the `END`

Comment: I am ashamed!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You probably try to execute all that script at once.
First create the function:

```
Create function GetDiffence (@difference float)
returns @Modify table
(Cod int, Pret float, Diferenta float)
as
begin
Insert @Modify
Select Cod, Pret, @difference-Pret as Diferenta
from PC_uri
order by Cod
Return
end
```

And than if it's successful you can try to call it:

```
Select * from GetDiffence(350)
```